# Difference between Future Simple and Future Progressive

Tags: grammar

The difference is that Future Simple is used when we talk about some action that will happen in the future.  And Future Continuous describes an action that will take place at a certain time in the future. Is it right?

- I will be preparing for my new job tomorrow.
- I will prepare for my new job tomorrow

What's right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. “At a certain point.”

Comment: Future Continuous normally describes a _continuing_ action that will take place in the future (_I will be playing tennis all this afternoon_), though in colloquial speech it can be used for a single action that is planned (_I will be coming home next week_).